# Equation for the reaction of iodide to iodine using hydrogen peroxide under acidic conditions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, home-experiment

I'm building a home lab around *All Lab, No Lecture Illustrated Guide to Home Chemistry Experiments* and I'd like to understand the chemistry that I'm doing a bit better. For example, here's an [iodine experiment](http://www.homechemlab.com/iodine.html).

> 1. Weigh out 2.0 g of potassium iodide and transfer it to a test tube.
> 2. Add about 1.5 mL of distilled water to the test tube and swirl to dissolve the potassium iodide.
> 3. Add 1.5 mL of concentrated hydrochloric acid (or about 1.8 mL of hardware store muriatic acid) to the test tube and swirl to mix the
>      solutions.
> 4. Add about 10 mL of drugstore 3% hydrogen peroxide. The solution immediately turns dark brown as the iodide ions are oxidized to
>      elemental iodine, which precipitates out.
> 5. Swirl the test tube to suspend the iodine and pour the liquid through a funnel with a folded piece of filter paper to capture the
>      iodine crystals.
> 6. Rinse the iodine crystals on the filter paper several times with a few mL of distilled water. The rinse solution appears brown from
>      dissolved iodine, but iodine is not very soluble in water, so you're
>      not losing much of your yield.
> 7. Spread out the filter paper on a watch glass or saucer and allow the crystals to dry thoroughly. Iodine gradually sublimates (passes
>      directly from solid to gaseous form) at room temperature, so don't
>      leave the crystals exposed to air any longer than necessary to dry
>      them.
> 8. Once the crystals are dry, transfer them to a sealed storage bottle or vial.

It's easy enough to follow and I know I have $$\ce{KI, H2O, HCl, H2O2}$$ with a result of $$\ce{I2\, +\, ???}$$ but then what?

I've had HS Chemistry, skipped Chem in college :(, so I know how to balance equations, convert from g or ml to moles, etc, but where can I learn to translate an experiment into equations without having to ask others (Textbooks or online resources are ideal, going and taking chem at a local uni. is a distant second, since I work fulltime)?

Currently I'm sticking to inorganic chem, so that should simplify things a bit.

I'm currently studying [EdX's Solid State Chemistry](https://www.edx.org/course/mitx/mitx-3-091x-introduction-solid-state-1751), so I hope that'll help some.

Comment: This is the reaction equation that you're looking for: $\ce{2 HCl + 2 KI + H2O2 -> I2 + 2 KCl + 2H2O}$ (source:http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=10202 , 2nd post)

Comment: Thank you. That was my "bonus" question. I suspected that the results were $$KCl,H_2O$$, but I wasn't sure. My main question still stands. Where can I learn to make that leap instead of always looking it up? Also, how do you do subscripts without using LaTeX?

Comment: @solarmist - we have the mhchem package for MathJax. Learn more [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88#88)

Comment: @LievenB - that equation is wrong. There isn't any unionized hydrochloric acid because it is a strong acid. It would be more reflective of chemical fact to write instead $H_3^+O$.

Comment: @Dissenter That's the essence of my question where can I learn to make that kind of call or determine the configuration of the product of a reaction?

Comment: Strong acids ionize completely in solution by definition. So what's really reacting isn't HCl but either $H_3^+O~or~Cl^-$.

Comment: @Dissenter but however the equation looks good is not a net ionic equation you can write it as you want...

Comment: True you can write the equation hiwever you want but what's happening in solution is independent of how you write the equation.

Answer (score 3):

We know that this is a redox situation, where iodide ion is oxidized to iodine, and where hydrogen peroxide is reduced to water.

The oxidation equation is as such: $\ce{2I- -> I2 + 2e-}$

The reduction equation is as such: $\ce{2H+ + H2O2 + 2e- -> 2H2O}$

Therefore, the overal equation is as such: $\ce{2H+ + H2O2 + 2I- -> 2H2O + I2}$

You can read more about redox reactions [here](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/redoxmenu.html).